# Scala Type Check and Conversion

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, type-conversion

I have a request.body coming into a controller and before I have anything done to it I want to check if it is an array. Else wrap it in an array and then proceed.

I tried this but I am not familiar enough with play scala to get it to work/ find the answer.

```
if (request.body.isInstanceOf[Array] == false) {
  var input = Array(request.body)
}
else {
  var input = request.body
}
```

My controller is

```
def insertMultiple = Action.async(parse.json) {
request =>
[INSERT IF/ELSE Statement here]
    Json.fromJson[Seq[Person]](request.body) match {
      case JsSuccess(newPersons, _) =>
        val documents = newPersons.map(implicitly[collection.ImplicitlyDocumentProducer](_))

        collection.bulkInsert(ordered = true)(documents: _*).map{
          multiResult =>
            Created(s"Created ${multiResult.n} persons")
        }

      case err@JsError(_) =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest("Test"))
    }
```

}

Comment: The default type of `body` (if you didn't define a body parser) is `AnyContent`, why do you think it might be an `Array`? Can you post the full  controller method that you're using?

Comment: basically I can add multiple people into the db but they come in as [{Person1},{Person2}]. However if a request come in with only {Person}, this method breaks. So I thought to try to wrap an Array around it to become [{Person}] to make the method work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// as long as you have an implicit Format[Person] in scope
// List[Person]
val people = r.body.validate[JsArray].asOpt.getOrElse {
  Json.arr(r.body)
}.as[List[Person]]
```

Comment: That worked! Correct me if I'm work but you validated the body as a JsArray and if that didn't return true you made the body into an array using Json.arr. What does asOpt do exactly?

Comment: also I didn't need the as[List[Person]]